# Get initial data of form fields

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a simple form that looks like this:

```
class SettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    theme = forms.CharField(required=True, initial='yellow')
    defaultinputmessage = forms.CharField(required=True, initial='Type here')
```

I can iterate over the form fields by doing this:

```
for field in SettingsForm().fields:
    print field
```

Is there a way I could access the default values for each of the form fields as well?

Thanks.

Comment: Anybody give answer in 2017 with django's latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for field in SettingsForm().fields:
    print field.initial
```

Answer (score 1):

for django1.4, this works

```
for k,v in SettingsForm().fields.iteritems():
    print v.initial
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something like this:

```
class SettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    theme = forms.CharField(required=True, initial='yellow')
    defaultinputmessage = forms.CharField(required=True, initial='Type here')

f = SettingsForm(auto_id=False)
    print f
```

Give it a try...